# ASP.NET MVC3 webdeploy: database deployment on production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webdeploy

I am using webdeploy to deploy my web application to IIS. I followed Microsoft's 12 part tutorial for this. I successfully deployed it on my local IIS.

I have to now deploy this to production and I am following the same steps. I am connected to the remote machine via VP. Form VS2010 publish profile the connection to the server was successful. But when I enter the DB connection string as 
"Data Source=xxxx\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=SWSS;Integrated Security=True"
and try to preview the Database, I get the following error:

```
Web deployment task failed. ((4/1/2013 9:18:42 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
(4/1/2013 9:18:42 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Member 'ClassName' was not found.
```

The remote machine does not have TCP/IP enabled. 
1. Is it safe to enable this in production machine? 
2. If not, how to deploy DB, taking advantage of the dbdacfx?

Update 1:

Based on the comments below, I have changed my connection string as follows:
"Data Source=SWSS\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=SWSS;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"

I created a sysadmin user in SQL server with SQL authentication rather than Windows authentication. Now the error is as follows:

```
Web deployment task failed. (Could not generate deployment script.
Unable to connect to target server.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)
```

Update 2:

Using mixed mode authentication on SQL Server fixed my issue.

Comment: Please provide userid and password in connection string.

Comment: When Integrated Security is True, why should we have user id and password? Doesnt Integrated Security mean to use the "Windows Authentication"

Comment: Remove Integrated Security use userid and password

Comment: what do you mean mixed mode authentication on SQL Server? could you elaborate that because I'm also having the same issue. thanks.. :)

Comment: @bot sorry it has been a while, but for others who are wondering about mixed mode authentication, please google it and there are several links explaining how to do it. briefly, it is to use both SQL server authentication and windows authentication.